# c# - my items are not moving from listbox1 to listbox2

Tags: c#, listboxitem

this is how my GUI looks like

[image]

I was working on a project for uni

what it does is reading a text-file

put it in listbox1

then the second button should take the students who succeed to listbox2

but whenever I press the button I get an error

I tried rly hard to search everywhere, but couldn't find the problem

it's just not writing it in listbox2 for no reason

anyone know what should I do?

what do I do to make it work???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace second_Project
{

    public partial class FSS : Form
    {
        private void FSS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public FSS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public class StdScore   
        {

            public int id;
            public string name;
            public double xam, Score, Pract;
            public string content;

            public string[] xx;


        }


        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StdScore StdScore = new StdScore();      

            ofd.Filter = "TXT|*.txt";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName);


                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {

                    StdScore.content = sr.ReadLine();

                    string[] info = StdScore.content.Split(' ');

                    StdScore.xx = new string[info.Length];

                    listBox1.Items.Add(StdScore.content);
                  
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StdScore StdScore = new StdScore();      


            StdScore.xam = 0;
            StdScore.Pract = 0;
            StdScore.Score = 0;

            StdScore.xam += int.Parse(StdScore.xx[2]);   

            StdScore.Pract += int.Parse(StdScore.xx[3]);  

            StdScore.Score = StdScore.xam * 0.7 + StdScore.Pract * 0.3; 



            if (StdScore.xam >= 40 && StdScore.Pract >= 40 && StdScore.Score >= 60)  
            {

                StdScore.xam = (StdScore.xam * 70) / 100;
                StdScore.Pract = (StdScore.Pract * 30) / 100;
                StdScore.Score = StdScore.xam + StdScore.Pract;

                listBox2.Items.Add(StdScore.xx[0] + " " + StdScore.xx[1] + " " + StdScore.xx[2] + " " + StdScore.xx[3] + " " + StdScore.Score + " " + "Succes");


            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Terry Tyson    its so tall my friend how do i get it in here ?

Comment: Edit the question and post the relevant part only?

Comment: it's all relevant, cuz I'm sure there something wrong somewhere, if u read what I wrote up there u would have known that I'm trying to make items go to listbox2, I wrote the code, but it's not working, that's why I shared the code and my GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the file, you have `listBox1.Items.Add(StdScore.content);`.  This simply adds a string to the ListBox.  You should create instances of `StdScore` INSIDE the while loop and add those instances directly to the ListBox.  It's a very bad practice to name your variable the exact same as the class itself.  I would expect to see something more like `StdScore curScore = new StdScore();`.  Now you can use `curScore` and it's clear this is an instance of the class and not the class itself, and you're not trying to access a static member.  For class `StdScore`, you can override the `ToString()` method to control what is displayed in the ListBox.

So here is `StdScore` with the `ToString()` override:

```
public class StdScore
{

    public int id;
    public string name;
    public double xam, Score, Pract;
    public string content;

    public string[] xx;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return content;
    }

}
```

Next, reading the file:

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    StdScore curScore = new StdScore();
    curScore.content = sr.ReadLine();
    curScore.xx = curScore.content.Split(' ');
    listBox1.Items.Add(curScore);
}
```

On to `button2` where you want to move students who succeed over to `listBox2`.  Here you need to ITERATE over all the stored `StdScore` instances that are within `listBox1`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(StdScore curScore in listBox1.Items)
    {
        curScore.xam = int.Parse(curScore.xx[2]);
        curScore.Pract = int.Parse(curScore.xx[3]);
        curScore.Score = curScore.xam * 0.7 + curScore.Pract * 0.3;

        if (curScore.xam >= 40 && curScore.Pract >= 40 && curScore.Score >= 60)
        {
            curScore.xam = (curScore.xam * 70) / 100;
            curScore.Pract = (curScore.Pract * 30) / 100;
            curScore.Score = curScore.xam + curScore.Pract;

            string success = curScore.xx[0] + " " + curScore.xx[1] + " " +
                curScore.xx[2] + " " + curScore.xx[3] + " " + curScore.Score + " Success";
            listBox2.Items.Add(success);
        }
    }                  
}
```

Note that from an **Object Oriented Programming** perspective, none of this code is correct.  The code can be much improved.  I simply took your existing code and changed it to "make it work"...at least I think it will; if not, it should give you some good ideas on where to make changes.